# Resizebox of Figure A kills Figure B with tikzexternalize in list and make mode

Tags: tikz-external, resize

I get a very peculiar error when using tikzexternalize in the list and make mode.
When I encapsulate a certain tikz-picture (Figure A) with resizebox another tikz Figure B picture fails to build with a dimension too large error in its log file.

If I either switch of externalization of Figure A temporarily with \tikzexternaldisable and \tikzexternalenable or if I remove the rezizebox, Figure B builds nicely.

I did not manage to get a MWE to reproduce the problem, so I'm guessing it has got to do with some other packages.

Just putting this out there in case somebody has had similar problems.

regards
Markus

This is all I get from the log:

```
A tikzpicture has been optimized away. Use '/tikz/external/optimize=false' to di
sable this.
)
! Dimension too large.
\Gscale@box ...\tw@ \hss }\else \hb@xt@ #1\wd \z@ 
                                                  {\box \tw@ \kern #1\wd \z@...
l.77 }
```

Im using lualatex from MacTeX 2020. I'm using latexmk to build externalized files automatically, but the problem also occurs when I manually do

```
lualatex document.tex
make -f document.makefile
```

Comment: usual reason for getting dim too large in connection with scaling is that the original length is, or is close to,  0pt so you get division by zero or arbitrarily large value. But without any example this question isn't really answerable as posted.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll try to come up with a MWE.